# Issue with my code trying to read a double

Tags: ios, swift

So I got the following code function to read string input at the console:

```
func input() -> String {
    let keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
}
```

The Issue I'm having is an interesting one. I'm attempting to get the resulting string input and cast it as a double.

```
//Accept user-input which is string then case into Double value for cakeLength
print("Please enter the length of the cake (in): ")
var userText = input()
cakeLength = Double(userText)!
```

For some odd reason, Xcode has told me to unwrap the Double(userText) part. However, when I attempt to run the code at the console, I get a run-time error that states: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to programming with Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need such a complicated function to read input from the console. The `readLine()` function from the [Standard Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:Fs8readLineFT12stripNewlineSb_GSqSS_) will do this for you nicely.

Secondly, you're forcing the unwrap of optional values (using `!`) where you don't know that the unwrap will succeed.

Here's a small example using Swifts [optional unwrapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) syntax that lets you check if there is a valid input, and also checks that the input can be cast to a Double:

```
import Foundation

print("Please enter the lenght of the cake (in):")

if let inputString = readLine(), inputDouble = Double(inputString) {
    print("The cake is \(inputDouble) inches")
} else {
    print("Your input couldn't be converted to a double")
}
```

Both `readLine()` and `Double()` return optionals (as they may not succeed) so you need to unwrap them before using, and also handle the case where they are nil. The `if let` statement is designed for this purpose.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I'm not allowed to use the readLine() function, otherwise I would. In regards to the unwrapping, it was initiated within Xcode's auto debugging.

Comment: Secondly, the compiler isn't asking you to unwrap the double "for some odd reason". Converting a string to a double may not work.. Consider `Double("hello")`... Would that work? No. So constructing a `Double` from a `String` returns an optional, as there may not be a valid double. I'd suggest looking at the string and seeing if it can be converted to a double.